# Does changing field of study have exclusively negative effects on my future career?

Tags: professionalism, career-development

I have recently completely my Bachelor's degree in physics with a 3.2 Grade Point Average.

However I am interested in the field of electronics and to this end I have decided to take a Master's in Electrical Engineering.

One of my professors however has opined that this is a complete change of field and that doing such a radical shift will negatively affect my future career prospects.

Is such a shift damaging to career prospects?

Comment: Do whatever makes you happy.

Comment: Welcome to Workplace SE! Unfortunately questions asking for help with specific career choices aren't suited to the SE model and would likely be closed - to avoid this I've edited your question. Hopefully the revised version still meets with your needs but if not you can rollback and do an edit of your own if desired.

Comment: Your professor is wrong.  They are just trying to keep you in their field.  Nothing better than having multiple-fields for your career.

Answer (score 2):

We can't decide what is the right choice for you.

Your professor is right that it could change your job field and opportunities, but that isn't a bad thing.  Engineering jobs would be different from pure physics jobs.  You need to try to review the types of jobs each path would lead to and decide which is more in line with your desires.